# MongoDB $match on object not considering key

Tags: mongodb

Please help compose a request.

```
[{
    name: 'Peter',
    items: {
        a: [1, 2, 3, 6],
        b: [0, 1],
        c: [4, 1]
    },
    name: 'Joe',
    items: {
        d: [2, 3],
        e: [0, 1],
    },
    name: 'Luk',
    items: {
        f: [0, 1, 8],
    },
}]
```

filter - items.xxx> 5

result - "Peter" and "Luk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   { $set: { items: { $objectToArray: "$items" } } },
   {
      $set: {
         items: {
            $reduce: {
               input: "$items.v",
               initialValue: [],
               in: { $concatArrays: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { items: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 5 } } } },
   { $project: { name: 1 } }
])
```

Result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3d7ed0ac00d5ec3a32125f"), 
    "name" : "Peter"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3d7ed0ac00d5ec3a321261"), 
    "name" : "Luk"
}
```

If you need the full documents, you can use this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $facet:
         {
            filter: [    
               { $set: { items: { $objectToArray: "$items" } } },
               {
                  $set: {
                     items: {
                        $reduce: {
                           input: "$items.v",
                           initialValue: [],
                           in: { $concatArrays: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               { $match: { items: { $elemMatch: { $gte: 5 } } } },
               { $project: { name: 1 } }    
            ],
            in: [{ $match: {} }],    
         }
   },
   { $unwind: "$in" },
   { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$in._id", "$filter._id"] } } },
   { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$in" } }
])
```

Comment: Thanks. You helped me a lot. The second option came up to me. Instead of $ set, I used $ project.